# httprequesttask returns JSONArray, not the expected JSONObject

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, database

I try to get patient information, by sending an ID to the server. I expect the result to be a JSONObject, as only one patient corresponds with the ID. However, what i get is a JSONArray. I have tried to do getJSONObject(0), but it gives this error:
Index 0 out of range [0..0)

Why i is an Array and not an Object, and how do i deal with it?

This is my java code in the activity:

```
new HttpRequestTask(
            "getPatientFull",
            new String[]{"ID"},
            new String[]{PatientID}, new HttpRequestTask.ResultReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void processResult(String apiFunctionName, JSONObject result) {
            if (result != null) {
                try {
                    if (result.has("error")) {
                        shorttoast("ERROR: " + result.getString("error") + "saving patient file");
                    } else {
                        if (result.has("patient_details")) {
                            patientName = result.getJSONArray("patient_details").getJSONObject(0).getString("NAME");
                            shorttoast(patientName);
                    }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException ex) {
                    shorttoast("ERROR" + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            } else
                shorttoast("Retreiving failed");
        }
    }).execute();
```

The PatientID is defined earlier in the code (it's an existing patient id).

and this is the php API function that was defined by my teacher:

```
 app.post("/getPatientFull", function (req, res) {
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM PatientDossier WHERE PATIENT_ID=?',
            [req.query.ID],
            function (error, results, fields) {
                if (error) {
                    res.status(403).json({"error": error.code});
                } else {
                    res.status(200).json({patient_details:results});
                }
            });
        connection.release();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP function does not return a single object, it returns an array.
So, you **should** expect a JSONArray on the Android side.

As to why getJSONObject(0) is giving you an out-of-bounds error, I'm not sure. 
Try using the debugger to look at the JSONArray, and see what's in it. It's possible that you searched for a patient id that's not in the database, and the PHP code returned an empty array. Your code should be checking that anyway.

It also looks like maybe "result" is a JSONObject containing the array, under the key "patient_details", in which case, you need to get the value of "patient_details" and index into that array. If you show us the JSON response, it would be easier to tell.